# Double increment of table counter

Tags: tables, captions, ltablex

I am currently setting up a skeleton for my thesis. I am using the KOMA Script report (`scrreprt`) documentclass:

```
\documentclass[titlepage,fonsize=10pt,a4paper,parskip=half,index=totoc,glossaries=totoc,bibliography=totoc,numbers=noenddot,dutch]{scrreprt}
```

For the captions of all the figures I use:

```
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,textformat=period]{caption}
```

For the references I have:

```
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}
```

And something generates the following problem. The identifiers (Table 9.x et cetera) now are only even numbers: Table 9.2, Table 9.4, et cetera. I played around with moving the tables around, but that does not help. For my tables I use the following format:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xlr}  
\toprule \textbf{Some column} & \textbf{Second column} & \textbf{Last column} \\ 
\midrule
Some row & with some & beautiful info \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Very useful information in the table}
\label{tbl:usefultable}
\end{table}
```

Is this expected behavior or am I doing something wrong? Because I would prefer to just get table identifiers starting from 1 and incrementing by 1.

---

```
\documentclass[titlepage,fonsize=10pt,a4paper,parskip=half,index=totoc,glossaries=totoc,bibliography=totoc,numbers=noenddot,dutch]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{ltablex,booktabs,float}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,textformat=period]{caption}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Some chapter}
\blindtext
\section{Some section}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xlr}  
\toprule \textbf{Some column} & \textbf{Second column} & \textbf{Last column} \\ 
\midrule
Some row & with some & beautiful info \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Very useful information in the table}
\label{tbl:usefultable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a compilable document, not just fragments. Welcome to TeX.SE! From the given 'code' there is no usage of `cleveref` identifyable

Comment: @ChristianHupfer  I added a compilable document.

Comment: Changed it again, was some testing of myself trying to fix it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put the `\caption` inside the `tabularx` command here. The `ltablex` package uses `longtable` effectively and transforms `tabularx` accordingly, so `\caption` should be inside of the `tabularx` environment.

The same error would occur for `longtable` itself.

```
\documentclass[titlepage,fonsize=10pt,a4paper,parskip=half,index=totoc,glossaries=totoc,bibliography=totoc,numbers=noenddot,dutch]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{ltablex,longtable,booktabs,float}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,textformat=period]{caption}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Some chapter}
\blindtext
\section{Some section}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{Xlr}
\toprule \textbf{Column one} & \textbf{Column two} & \textbf{Column three} \\
\midrule
Some row & with some & useful content\\
Some row & with some & useful content\\
Some row & with some & useful content\\
Some row & with some & useful content\\
Some row & with some & useful content\\
Some row & with some & useful content\\
\bottomrule
\caption{Some useful table}\label{tbl:deadlines}
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{Xlr}
\toprule \textbf{Column one} & \textbf{Column two} & \textbf{Column three} \\
\midrule
Some row & with some & useful content\\
Some row & with some & useful content\\
Some row & with some & useful content\\
Some row & with some & useful content\\
Some row & with some & useful content\\
Some row & with some & useful content\\
\bottomrule
\caption{Some useful table}\label{tbl:deadlines:again}
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```