# Caption inside tabularx causes error (no line to end)

Tags: captions, tabularx

I'm trying to use a caption inside a non floating tabularx.

Until now I used \captionof but this causes the counter to increment twice due to the underlying use of longtable as far as I understood. So I need to switch to a caption inside the tabularx.

When I add \caption inside the table it produces the following error:

```
There's no line here to end.
```

The following sample produces the error:

```
% Preamble
% ---
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
% Packages
% ---
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Unicode support (Umlauts etc.)
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % Change hyphenation rules
\usepackage[a4paper, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Add pictures to your document
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ltablex} % Span tables over pages
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\alph{subsection}}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedright}m{#1}}
\begin{document}
\title{Some title}

\tableofcontents{}
\newpage
\section{Foo}
\subsection{bar}
\subsubsection*{Foo}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|R{3cm}|R{3cm}|X|p{1.5cm}|}
        \hline
        A
         & B
         & C
         & D
        \\
        \hline
        Lorem ipsum
         & Lorem ipsum
         & Lorem ipsum
         & 1
        \\
        \hline
        Some text
         & some more text
         & blah 
        blahh
         & 2
        \\
        \hline
        \caption{Some Caption}
    \end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\caption` should be outside the tabularx normally in a table

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have done this but the user is not happy for this.

Comment: use `\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}`

Comment: @ulrike-fischer Thank you! That was causing the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two separate issues with your code.

- The first, and more pressing one, is related to the not-exactly-helpful error message you've encountered. What's going on is that `\caption` must occur inside a `table` or `figure` float (LaTeX jargon alert). Also, `\caption` must not occur inside a `tabular`-like environment, such as `tabularx`. The two step remedy: (a) replace `\caption{Some Caption}` with `\captionof{table}{Some Caption}` and (b) place this instruction after rather than before `\end{tabularx}`.
- The second issue is that you shouldn't load both `tabularx` and `ltablex` -- unless you know *exactly* what you're doing. (Most users don't...) The main symptom, for the table at hand, is that the actual width of the `tabularx` environment falls far short of the desired or target width. The remedy, for the test document at hand? Don't load the `ltablex` package. Instead, load the [xltabular](https://ctan.org/pkg/xltabular) package, which directly combines the capabilities of the `longtable` and `tabularx` packages. Basically, an `xltabular` environment is a `longtable` environment that knows about the `X` column type provided by `tabularx`, but without modifying/clobbering the properties of `tabularx`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
% Packages
% ---
%%%%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % <-- new
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % Change hyphenation rules
\usepackage[a4paper, hmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Add pictures to your document
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
%%%%\usepackage{ltablex} % Span tables over pages
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\alph{subsection}}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

%%%%\usepackage{listingsutf8}
%%%%\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[usenames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}} % <-- new

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|R{3cm}|R{3cm}|X|p{1.5cm}|}
        \hline
           A
         & B
         & C
         & D
        \\
        \hline
           Lorem ipsum
         & Lorem ipsum
         & Lorem ipsum
         & 1
        \\
        \hline
           Some text
         & some more text
         & blah 
        blahh
         & 2
        \\
        \hline 
\end{tabularx}
\captionof{table}{Some Caption}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: ltablex loads tabularx too, so loading tabularx doesn't harm. And it redefines tabularx to be a longtable, which means that \caption should be used inside the tabular similar to the way longtable uses it. The documentation contains an example of this. xltabular loads ltablex and basically copies its code (only in a new environment instead of overwriting tabularx).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - So what's causing the width of the OP's `tabularx` example to fall far short of the target width (here: `\textwidth`)? As soon as I comment out (or delete) the instruction `\usepackage{ltablex}`, this problem ceases to exist.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - I'm much more comfortable recommending that users employ the `xltabular` package, which doesn't redefine (clobber, in my view...) the  properties of `tabularx`.

Comment: sure xltabular is an option and probably a bit safer that ltablex, but it errors too in the example of the OP with the \raggedright (I tried that).

Answer (score 0):

Manually set the caption number using `\addtocounter{table}{-1}` before the first table to reset the counter, then increment it by one using `\stepcounter{table}` after the table. The caption numbering starts from 1 for the first table and increments correctly for subsequent tables.

```
% Preamble
% ---
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
% Packages
% ---
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Unicode support (Umlauts etc.)
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % Change hyphenation rules
\usepackage[a4paper, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Add pictures to your document
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ltablex} % Span tables over pages
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\alph{subsection}}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedright}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\title{Some title}

\tableofcontents{}
\newpage
\section{Foo}
\subsection{bar}
\subsubsection*{Foo}

% Reset the counter for the caption
\addtocounter{table}{-1}

\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|R{3cm}|R{3cm}|X|p{1.5cm}|}
        \hline
        A & B & C & D \\
        \hline
        Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum & 1 \\
        \hline
        Some text & some more text & blah blahh & 2 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{Some Caption} % Add caption with numbering
\end{table}

% Increment the counter for the next caption
\stepcounter{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As you can see captionof causes the caption to increment twice, in your example 2. This is due to longtable being used internally. Suggestions online recommended to use caption inside tabularx.

Comment: @KevKosDev See my edit. Unfortunately often I not undersood the English language very well. If there are problem yet I delete my code.

Comment: This compiles, but the caption still starts with 2 instead of 1. So this problem: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353652/double-increment-of-table-counter

Comment: @KevKosDev You see now my last edit.

Comment: @KevKosDev captionof will not be evaluated twice if you put it outside the tabularx as intended

Comment: It will and as far as I understand its due to the ltablex package, which I need.

Comment: @KevKosDev - Don't load the `ltablex` package, which clashes with `tabularx`. Instead, load the much more modern  [xltabular](https://ctan.org/pkg/xltabular) package, which combines the features of the `longtable` and `tabularx` package in a very natural way.